# Merge values in dataframe columns to create new column of lists

Tags: r, list, dataframe, merge

I have a dataframe with some 100 columns. I would like to merge the values in the first 29 columns together in a list. So a new column should be created where each row contains a list of the values. The trick is that often there are empty cells in the first 29 columns so sometimes the lists will contain 5 elements, sometimes 7 elements, 20 elements, etc.

Dummy dataframe example:

```
   one = c(2.34, 3.345, 5.345) 
   two = c(2354.2, 5234.23, 43) 
   three = c(2643, 434.34, 5.345) 
   df = data.frame(one, two , three)
```

Desired variable:

```
   ([2.34, 2354.2, 2643], [3.345, 5234.23, 434.340], [5.345, 43.00, 5.345])
```

Comment: Maybe something like: `apply(df, 1, toString)` and for the `NAs` -- perhaps: `apply(df, 1, function(x) { toString(Filter(function(f) !is.na(f), x)) } )`

Comment: It'd be great if you could update your example and desired output to cover the case where *"sometimes the lists will contain 5 elements, sometimes 7 elements, 20 elements"*; it's not clear.

Answer (score 0):

```
lapply(1:nrow(df), function(x) unname(df[x, ]))
# [[1]]
#                   
# 1 2.34 2354.2 2643
# 
# [[2]]
#                       
# 2 3.345 5234.23 434.34
# 
# [[3]]
#                 
# 3 5.345 43 5.345
```

Comment: Thanks, what if I wanted each row to correspond to a vector of the values instead of a list?

Comment: There are no rows, this is a list of vectors. Are you just looking for `t(df)`? Perhaps you can clarify the output you are looking for? Provide it in valid R syntax? `([2.34, 2354.2, 2643], [3.345, 5234.23, 434.340], [5.345, 43.00, 5.345])` isn't super clear.

Comment: I also have no idea what you mean by "*sometimes the lists will contain 5 elements, sometimes 7 elements, 20 elements*", this doesn't seem to be reflected in your sample data, nor in your desire for "rows" of output.